# Convexifying Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

Let $\mathbf{V} \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n \times m}$ and $\mathbf{E} \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n \times m}$.

I am trying to convexify the following program which solves for $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$:

\begin{align}
 &\max &\sum_{i = 1}^n \log \left(\sum_{j = 1}^n V_{ij}\left( X_{ij} - E_{ij} \right)\right) - \sum_{i = 1}^n \log\left(\sum_{j = 1}^m X_{ij} - E_{ij}\right)\\
&\forall j \in \{1, \dots, m\} & \sum_{i = 1}^n X_{ij} \leq 1\\
&\forall i \in \{1, \dots, n\}, j \in \{1, \dots, m\} & X_{ij} \geq 0
\end{align}

I tried putting $\sum_{i = 1}^n \log(\sum_{j = 1}^m X_{ij} - E_{ij})$ as a constraint using a dummy variable but I do not think I am doing it correctly since my solver tells me that the program is not convex.

How can I convexify this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be convexified by Difference of Convex (DC) Programming.

See [DC Programming: The Optimization Method You Never Knew You Had To Know](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-097-prediction-machine-learning-and-statistics-spring-2012/projects/MIT15_097S12_proj5.pdf).

[Variations and extension of the convex–concave procedure, Thomas Lipp1 and Stephen Boyd](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/cvx_ccv.pdf)

A modeling system such as CVXPY which supports [Disciplined Convex-Concave Programming (DCCP)](https://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/dccp.pdf) makes it easy to enter this problem, and let the modeling syetm do the dirty work for you, while reducing human error propensity.

Comment: Just a question regarding CVXPY. I actually tried to solve this in CVXPY, but I got the following message "Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The objective is not DCP." Do I have to pass in a specific argument or something?

Comment: You have to install the DCCP package as CVXPY extension  https://github.com/cvxgrp/dccp . Also see https://www.cvxpy.org/related_projects/index.html?highlight=dccp .

Comment: Thanks Mark! These are excellent resources and are very helpful for me!